# Spotfire - How to show labels for combination bars stacked bar 100%

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

How can I show labels for each series of the combination bars? Would have some way with a IronPython script or configuration properties?

[Graph spotfire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcSZe.png)

Comment: it looks like you have labels for each series. are you instead trying to show labels for each segment? this is not possible in Spotfire 7.14; you can only show the total value for the bar. the value can be displayed in a tooltip, however.

Comment: Exactly, for each segment. It's not possible as IronPython?

Comment: Using bar charts it is possible to do this, but the bar chart in compensation is more difficult to plot a line target as a series. Do you have some suggestion to create this view?

Comment: no, there is no possibility with IronPython. there is a Spotfire extension called JSViz that you can use to develop a custom visualization and create this functionality yourself, but the effort to create this is quite high.

Comment: yes, a regular bar chart does have this feature, but the combination chart does not.